# What is the use of 'length.out' and 'along.with' arguments in gslider()?

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

What is the use of `length.out` and `along.with` arguments in [gslider()](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/gWidgets2/html/gslider.html) from [gWidgets2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets2/)? In `?gslider` I can only see (the rather counter-intuitive):

```
by              step size if not specified by from
length.out      in place of by
along.with      in place of length.out
```

Does this imply that the three arguments are synonyms?

Comment: Take a look at `?seq` - therein lie the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the source code.

```
 if (!is.null(length.out)) {
   by <- (to - from)/(length.out[1] - 1)
 }
```

If present, say `length.out = 5`, it sets `by` to be `(to - from) / 4`. As for the latter,

```
if (!missing(along.with)) {
   length.out <- length(along.with)
}
```

it allows you to, e.g., pass a list of length `n` and then `length.out` will be `n`. I won't speak as to the usefulness of these arguments but I guess the author must have thought they'd come in handy.

Comment: I was trying to mimim `seq` so that it seemed natural to an R user. Maybe I missed :)